# Export and Import Pages Elementor from Localhost into live website

Tags: wordpress, localhost, elementor

Hello I'm new in elementor.

I want to export and import pages I created by elementor from localhost into live website but it's show only blank page after I imported. Does anyone know why? Is there's solution for that?

Thankyou

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.